# How to display polyline on mouse clicks C++ WinAPI?

Tags: c++, winapi, plot, win32gui

It is required to first translate the source point to the origin (done by each), and then, when you click the mouse at the point, connect it to a unique line. At the moment, for each point, a new point of treatment is simply with the origin

```
    {
        HDC hdc;
        WORD xPos, yPos, nSize;
        TCHAR szBuf[80];
        DWORD dw;
        HANDLE File;
        RECT rc;
        GetClientRect (hWnd, &rc); // client window size

        const int xW = rc.right;
        const int yW = rc.bottom;

        //Отображение координат клика на окошке
        xPos = LOWORD(lp);
        yPos = HIWORD(lp);
        hdc = GetDC(hWnd);

        if (xPos > 0 & yPos > 0 & xPos < xW & yPos < yW)
        {
            HDC hDC;

            hDC=BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
            hDC=GetDC(hWnd);
            HBRUSH hBrush;
            hBrush=CreateSolidBrush(RGB(255,0,0));
            SelectObject(hDC,hBrush);
            Ellipse(hDC, xPos - 4, yPos - 4, xPos + 4, yPos + 4);
            MoveToEx(hDC, 20, yW / 2, NULL);
            LineTo(hDC, xPos, yPos);
            EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        }
}
```

[incorrect picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n8ptn.png)

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please take the [tour] and read about [ask] good questions. Lastly please read [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: [LineTo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-lineto) doesn't move  the current position. You may need [PolylineTo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-polylineto). And also have a look at [Drawing Markers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdi/drawing-markers).